# Should these CPU temperatures worry me?

Tags: cpu, temperature, xeon

I have a Dell T7500 with 2 X5675 processors.

I am running Linux Ubuntu.

When I type in sensors, I get this:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan:  720 RPM
Processor Fan: 1332 RPM
Ambient:        +18.0°C  
Other:          +40.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +65.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 1:       +68.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 2:       +67.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 8:       +68.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 9:       +68.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 10:      +67.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +83.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 1:       +84.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 2:       +81.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 8:       +82.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 9:       +83.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 10:      +83.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
```

Is it normal for one of the CPUs to be so much hotter than the other?

Does it matter that it is running above the "high" of +80.0C?

The job that I am running heats up the CPU to around 84C for a couple of minutes. Then lets it take a break and cool to around 70C. And then repeats many times.

Is this behaviour going to damage my hardware?

Comment: Have you checked the computer for excessive dust and checked that the fans are securely mounted to the CPUs?

Comment: No. I am not a hardware guy. but I'll get myself an air duster.

Comment: But yourself some thermal paste